# My code (Python) is trying to select a bunch of CSS from certain areas

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code is trying to select a bunch of CSS from certain areas however I can't seem to figure out what to select. I'm using Python, bs4, requests and pandas.
This is what my code is atm.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as re

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://forum.sa-mp.com/search.php?searchid=22924663'

response = re.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

body = soup.select_one('#inlinemodform > .alt1').text

with open('always.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(body + "\n")

print(body)
```

This is what I'm trying to select.
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFmFp.png)

The link for the web page is https://forum.sa-mp.com/search.php?searchid=22924663 incase you haven't already figured. I doubt you'll be able to access it without creating an account sadly. Hope you can help!

Comment: yes, you need to login. otherwise you would not find any images. you have to add login function in your script